# Web query data in excel with vba

Tags: excel, loops, vba

Myself Bunty, I am working on a tiny assignment and my task to analyze data into a excel sheet. For this, i have to import data from 200 different urls and paste the data in excel for further doing analysis.
I am able to pull data from a cell and paste it into another cell with the help of this vba code.

```
Sub UseDynamicURL()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim src As Worksheet
Dim tgt As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set src = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set tgt = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim url As String
Dim symbol As String

symbol = src.Range("A1")
url = "URL;http://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s="
url = url & symbol & "+Income+Statement&annual"

With tgt.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    url, _
    Destination:=tgt.Range("A1"))

    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    .SaveData = True
End With
End Sub
```

.
This code is written by Jon Crowell. Now, can anyone help me modify it as per my requirement. In sheet 1, I have 200 values in column A and want the pulled data in sheet 2 in cells A1,A15,A29 and so on...
Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: might be easier with the Google Sheets GOOGLEFINANCE function, or Power Query  in Excel 2010+ https://medium.com/@dtomoffcpa/microsoft-excel-basic-powerquery-stock-price-data-from-google-sheets-7354438c0882

Comment: Thanks. But i just want to add a loop or something in the above code only.

Comment: I am wondering why no one is able to put a loop in it...